# On structure of every ideal of the product ring $R_1\times R_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

**The Problem  is:** Let, $R_1$ and $R_2$ be two rings (with no mention of identity in either rings), then $R_1\times R_2$ forms a ring with component wise addition and multiplication.
Then, give example of a ring $R = R_1\times R_2$ such that there exists an ideal $I$ of $R$ which is not of the form $I_1\times I_2$ for any $I_1$ and $I_2$ which are being ideals of $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively .

**My approach :** I found a proof of a problem that if $R = R_1\times R_2$ contains the identity, then every ideal of $R$ is of the form $I_1\times I_2 .$ Rather, we know that every subgroup of a direct product of groups is not necessarily a direct product of subgroups of the component groups, then I was checking those subgroups were forming subrings or not by taking an example of the group $\mathbb Z_{14} \times \mathbb Z_7$, but it was not happening . 
Hence, I need hints to proceed further .

**Bonus :** What condition(s) is(are) to be imposed on $R$ such that every subring of $R$ is of the form $S_1\times S_2$ ???

Comment: Your approach doesn't seem to make sense. It's true that for unital rings, the ideals of $R_1 \times R_2$ are always of the form $I_1 \times I_2$, but I cannot understand what you mean by "we know that every subgroup of a direct product of groups is not necessarily a direct product of subgroups of the component groups, then I tried to prove those subgroups as subrings by taking the group $\mathbb{Z}_{14} \times \mathbb{Z}_7$". Did you mean to say that you wanted to show that any additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{14} \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ *not* of the form $I_1 \times I_2$ is not an ideal?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, no Sir, I was checking that the subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{14} \times \mathbb Z_7$ which are not of the form $S_1\times S_2$ were forming subrings or not.